Import start layout menu
I ask about importing start menu layout xml file.
I would appreciate it if your reply has no outer links.
How can I use this importing to an online running window 10, given the fact I'm a single an only user with no new users at all.
Should I import it to my USB installer before any installation has started ?
How?
Thanx
